# no error but cannot load image in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmapimage

the code is here,designer window has a button and a picture box!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

    dlg.Title = "Open Image";
    dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        PictureBox PictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
        /* PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);

            // Add the new control to its parent's controls collection
            this.Controls.Add(PictureBox1);
            //dlg.Dispose();*/
    }
}
```

there is no error the window opens,when i press the button it opens directory ,then selected the image ,but it is not able to load  the image in the  window. the image im loading is 49.6 MB ,does that create any problem.

Comment: You have to add the PictureBox1 to the Form control collection as you have done it in the disabled code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've commented out the part where you added the picturebox to your window, id also suggest setting some elementary width/height of the picturebox so you can be sure it shows on screen.

Does it work with a much smaller test image?

Comment: @Bug Finder...only the part of the image is being displaced on top left corner(where there is a button to load the image) under the button

Comment: sorry its displayed!! on top left corner

Comment: Yes, it would be. You didnt give it alternative places to load.  By default the picture box would be top left and possibly very small, as you are creating it on the fly you would need to resize and reposition with top/left and height/width (height/width you can get from the picture if necessary)

Comment: the image resolution 3500*4958!! how do i resize and reposition it and set its width/height!! please bare with me i m just a beginner

Comment: To position it, as I said, set top and left, just like all controls (check properties of them on your form) Google is your friend - an example resize code goes : http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

Comment: actually image is not even loading in picture box but on window form!!

Comment: Well the code should work if the source to the picture was correct. (and you had said it was showing top left) So, you need to be more specific with your issues. I did a test one, my picture box was on the form, it loaded my ugly photo I found, I could resize it.. Once again, are you sure you set a size for your picturebox? and that its not 0,0 in size? Debug, this is the best way to learn

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the picture box on the fly, put it wherever you like in the Designer and set its Visible property to False.

Assuming you will name it `PictureBox1` just assign its Image whenever the button is pressed, without creating any new picture box and in addition change its Visible to `true`:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
PictureBox1.Visible = true;
```

With your current code, the picture box gets default position of 0,0 which means top left corner of the window.

Comment: Wizard ...PictureBox1.Visible = true; this property i have set.even though the result is same,but i could'nt get what u said "just assign its Image whenever the button is pressed, without creating any new picture box " i think the which i mentioned is the same one!

Comment: @raghu in the code you posted you **create** the picture box with code. Instead of doing this, have it already in your form same way you have the button. Hope it's clear now?

Comment: @shadow...there is code written for button and little code to take the filename and display in picture box..and i have just placed the picture box in the window so that when i press the button it opens the open file dialog and the image displays in the picture box..

Comment: @raghu so please update your question with the new relevant code.. also explain what is the problem.

Comment: i will xplain wat i have done!the code is the same i have pasted with a little correction i.e adding this.Controls.Add(PictureBox1); In the designer window  i added the button to browse and load the image,and picture box also ,made it dock right ( if its fill,it is covering complete window),there is no error but i could see only a part of the image at top left corner(u said by default it will be like that)but how to change it dispaly beside the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
PictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
PictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```